# using SparkSQL to join two tables on cassandra - ERROR: missing EOF

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I installed Cassandra and Spark with SparkSQL on my machine.
Spark SQL support JOIN Keyword

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlSupportedSyntax.html

> Supported syntax of Spark SQL The following syntax defines a SELECT
>   query.
>
> SELECT [DISTINCT] [column names]|[wildcard]  FROM [kesypace
>   name.]table name  [JOIN clause table name ON join condition] [WHERE
>   condition] [GROUP BY column name] [HAVING conditions] [ORDER BY column
>   names [ASC | DSC]]

I have the following code

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My application").setMaster("local");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sc.getConf());
Session session = connector.openSession();

ResultSet results;
String sql ="";


BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
sql = "SELECT * from siem.report JOIN siem.netstat on siem.report.REPORTUUID = siem.netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID ALLOW FILTERING;";
results = session.execute(sql);
```

I get the following error

> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:25
>   missing EOF at ',' (SELECT * from siem.report[,] siem...) 11:14 AM 
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:25 missing EOF
>   at ',' (SELECT * from siem.report[,] siem...) at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
>   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
>   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
>   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
>   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:63)
>   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:33)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.execute(Unknown Source) at
>   com.ge.predix.rmd.siem.boot.PersistenceTest.test_QuerySparkOnReport_GIACOMO_LogDao(PersistenceTest.java:178)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements

also tried with

```
SELECT * from siem.report JOIN siem.netstat on report.REPORTUUID = netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID ALLOW FILTERING
```

also tried with

```
SELECT * from siem.report R JOIN siem.netstat N on R.REPORTUUID = N.NETSTATREPORTUUID ALLOW FILTERING
```

can someone help me? I'm really using SparkSQL or CQL?

## UPDATE

I tried

```
public void test_JOIN_on_Cassandra () {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My application").setMaster("local");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);


        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        try {
            //QueryExecution test1 = sqlContext.executeSql("SELECT * from siem.report");
            //QueryExecution test2 = sqlContext.executeSql("SELECT * from siem.report JOIN siem.netstat on report.REPORTUUID = netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID");
            QueryExecution test3 = sqlContext.executeSql("SELECT * from siem.report JOIN siem.netstat on siem.report.REPORTUUID = siem.netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       // SchemaRDD results = sc.sql("SELECT * from siem.report JOIN siem.netstat on siem.report.REPORTUUID = siem.netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID");

}
```

and I get

> == Parsed Logical Plan == 'Project [unresolvedalias(*)]
>   +- 'Join Inner, Some(('siem.report.REPORTUUID = 'siem.netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID))    :- 'UnresolvedRelation
>   `siem`.`report`, None    +- 'UnresolvedRelation `siem`.`netstat`, None
>   == Analyzed Logical Plan == org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedException: Invalid
>   call to toAttribute on unresolved object, tree: unresolvedalias(*)
>   'Project [unresolvedalias(*)]
>   +- 'Join Inner, Some(('siem.report.REPORTUUID = 'siem.netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID))    :- 'UnresolvedRelation
>   `siem`.`report`, None    +- 'UnresolvedRelation `siem`.`netstat`, None
>   == Optimized Logical Plan == org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `siem`.`report`;
>   == Physical Plan == org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `siem`.`report`;

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are blending a couple concepts here that are creating an error. The session you are creating will open a direct line to Cassandra, meaning it will accept CQL not SQL. If you want to run SQL you can make a small change

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My application").setMaster("local");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

SchemaRDD results = sparkContext.sql("SELECT * from siem.report JOIN siem.netstat on siem.report.REPORTUUID = siem.netstat.NETSTATREPORTUUID");
```

You call SparkSQL from the Spark Context instead of connecting to Cassandra directly. More here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlJava.html